# How to do i fix this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key staticDataSource

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

```
responseString = {"Status":"Success","Message":"Login Success"}
{
    Message = "Login Success";
    Status = Success;
}
result: Success

2017-06-15 21:53:15.592 PETIMATE[1479:69189] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PETIMATE.More_FEED 0x7fbde34ae050> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key staticDataSource.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ce8d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105c5ddeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ce89c9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001040bb19b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001046a5d0c -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001048dc7fb -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c22890 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001048db1de -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001046ac8d6 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001046ad202 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001046ad560 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001046adcd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001047111bc -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 502
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104710130 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010470bf41 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 377
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010470bdb7 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 234
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010470ffa1 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 481
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000104514a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001048f2066 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 498
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000104514a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000104687e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000104688143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001048f71bb -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 103
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000104514a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000104687e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000104688143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000104687263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010458799f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    28  UIKit                               0x00000001045886d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000104533dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010450d553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c0e301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c0422c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c036e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c030f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108478ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000104512f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    37  PETIMATE                            0x000000010374ff52 main + 114
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105bbf92d start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is my error. I search google this error not found.

In my storyboard I connect relations from TabbarView to TableView ->(in tableview is Statics cell) and i put class in TableView is UIViewcontroller

figure 1 : relations of TabbarView and TableView
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpvax.png)

figure 2: class of tableView
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYrTN.png)

How to do fix error or terminate.
if who know,help me please.
Thank you.

p.s. Sorry for my language i not strength English Language.

Comment: check IBoutlet connection at More_Feed controller, i think you have connect datasource and delegate of tableview in stroyboard but did't mention any delegate and datasource method in .swift file of controller.

Comment: Where did you got this error?Can you post your code?

Comment: answer to DS Dharma i can't post code i'm sorry.But my code before drag relations from Tabbar to Table(included class).i do not know this error .thank for answer to me.

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE:   For me the problem was that my View was inheriting from UIVewController and it needed to inherit from UITableViewController.  Then the framework creates the staticDataSource that the exception is saying it needs.  I found this blog that explains this:  https://blog.alwold.com/2012/02/28/static-table-cells-in-ios-4/    It is not a duplicate because when the excep involves staticDataSource that indicates this error. The target question is not specifically about staticDataSource.